# A question re: "A Mathematician Plays the Stock Market"

Tags: probability

Excerpt here:

> A contrived but interesting illustration of a self-fulfilling belief involves a tiny investment club with only two investors and ten possible stocks to choose from each week. Let's assume that each week chance smiles at random on one of the ten stocks the investment club is considering and it rises precipitously, while the week's other nine stocks oscillate within a fairly narrow band.
>
> George, who believes (correctly in this case) that the movements of stock prices are largely random, selects one of the ten stocks by rolling a die (say an icosahedron -- a twenty-sided solid -- with two sides for each number). Martha, let's assume, fervently believes in some wacky theory, Q analysis. Her choices are therefore dictated by a weekly Q analysis newsletter that selects one stock of the ten as most likely to break out. Although George and Martha are equally likely to pick the lucky stock each week, the newsletter-selected stock will result in big investor gains more frequently than will any other stock.
>
> The reason is simple but easy to miss. Two conditions must be met for a stock to result in big gains for an investor: It must be smiled upon by chance that week and it must be chosen by one of the two investors. Since Martha always picks the newsletter-selected stock, the second condition in her case is always met, so whenever chance happens to favor it, it results in big gains for her. This is not the case with the other stocks. Nine-tenths of the time, chance will smile on one of the stocks that is not newsletter-selected, but chances are George will not have picked that particular one, and so it will seldom result in big gains for him. One must be careful in interpreting this, however. George and Martha have equal chances of pulling down big gains (10 percent), and each stock of the ten has an equal chance of being smiled upon by chance (10 percent), but the newsletter-selected stock will achieve big gains much more often than the randomly selected ones.

I don't see how picking what the newsletter recommends (Martha) would yield gains more frequently than a random choice (George). Consider if the newsletter itself were just rolling a die to make its selection -- then there's no difference between Martha or George in their approach.

I'm wary to suggest Paulos has made an error here, so I'm assuming I'm the one who's erred. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? Thank you.

Here's from the next page in the book:

> Reiternated more numerically, the claim is that 10 percent of the time the newsletter-selected stock will achieve big gains for Martha, whereas each of the ten stocks has only a 1 percent chance of both achieving big gains *and* being chosen by George. Note again that two things must occur for the newsletter-selected stock to achieve big gains: Martha must choose it, which happens with probability 
>   $1$, and it must be the stock that chance selects, which happens with probability $1/10$th. Since one multiplies probabilities to determine the likelihood that several independent events occur, the probability of both these events occurring is $1 \times 1/10$, or 10 percent. Likewise, two things must occur for any particular stock to achieve big gains via George: George must choose it, which occurs with probability $1/10$th, and it must be the stock that chance selects, which happens with probability $1/10$th. The product of these two probabilities is $1/100$th or 1 percent.
>
> Nothing in this thought experiment depends on there being only two investors. If there were one hundred investors, fifty of whom slavishly followed the advice of the newsletter and fifty of whom chose stocks at random, then the newsletter-selected stocks would achieve big gains for their investors eleven times as frequently as any particular stock did for its investors. When the newsletter-selected stock is chosen by chance and happens to achieve big gains, there are fifty-five winners, the fifty believers in the newsletter and five who picked the same stock at random. When any of the other nine stocks happens to achieve big gains, there are, on average, only five winners.
>
> In this way a trading strategy, if looked at in a small population of investors and stocks, can give the strong illusion that it is effective when it is only chance at work.

Comment: I think without more context this is going to be very hard to answer. For instance, the line: "... and it must be chosen by one of the two investors". Why, for a stock to go up, must it be chosen by one of the two investors? I suspect the answer to your question is hidden in the answer to mine.

Comment: Sorry! I've added some additional verbiage from the book, both before and after the original excerpt.

Comment: I have to say, although you addressed my comment so I don't want to be too harsh -- this isn't really a very good m.se question. Generally linking to images of text is a bad practice, and I don't really have the inclination to read all that. I suggest closing this and making a new question where you concisely state the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What's key is the sentence

"the news-letter selected stock will result in big investor gains more frequently than will any other stock."

The question is not "whether the newsletter selected stock does better than a randomly chosen stock". The question is: *given the investment strategies of George and Martha*, whether any other choice of stock will outperform *for the investing club as a whole* the newsletter stock.

To make extremely explicit: Given a sequence of stock choices $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n$, we count the number of times that $s_i$ hit it big while it is in the portfolio of Martha and add to it the number of times that $s_i$ hit it big while it is in the portfolio of George.

For the Q-analysis sequence, at every stage there is 1/10 chance that the chosen stock hits it big. When that happens, there is a 1/10 chance that George picked that stock. This means that in general there is a **11%** chance that the stock picked by the Q-newsletter will result in observed invest**OR** gains.

If you choose any sequence of stocks that **avoids** the Q-analysis sequence, at every stage there is still a 1/10 chance that the chosen stock hits it big. When that happens, there is 0 chance that Martha picked it, but there is a 1/10 chance that George picked it. This means that in general there is a **1%** chance that any non-Q-analysis sequence will result in observed invest**OR** gains.

---

Obviously, this weird result will no longer hold if you have a large number of investors each following divergent investment strategies (say, if everyone picks stocks at random).

---

Another way to think about this is: **you** want to think about the question "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?", but the book is talking about the question "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does anyone hear a sound?" The answer to this second question is definitely "no".

Answer (score 1):

The book is nonsense.  The statement "the newsletter selected stock will result in big investor gains more often than any other stock" is wrong because the George selected stock will result in big investor gains just as often as the newsletter selected stock.  The book says the newsletter is no smarter than George.  We can do the same calculation centered on George and find that George gets big gains $10\%$ of the time and any other stock only achieves big investor gains $1\%$ of the time because the newsletter only buys it $10\%$ of the time.  If we had nine Georges, who conspired to each choose a different stock than the others and the newsletter, each stock would be bought every week and each stock would result in big investor gains $10\%$ of the time.  The problem is the book's interpretation of "any other stock".

Answer (score 0):

Per the author's final sentence in the excerpt, their point seems to be: "If you do math incorrectly, you can see unexpected results." Any reasonable analysis would of course compare strategies and investment returns, and it would find the approaches to be comparable.